Driver JDBC No se encuentra en GX18 U10
Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede apoyar, llevo días tratando de configurar un Datastore a Mysql por JDBC en Genexus 18 U10 con Java.
Tengo Instalado el Mysql Server 8.0.35 y el Connector JDBC 9.0.1 se encuentra declarado en el Classpath del sistema.

En Genexus, al tratar de realizar un test a la base de datos aparece que no hay un driver JDBC instalado.

Si realizo la prueba por terminal, logra encontrar la clase (com.mysql.cj.jdbc) del conector y hacer una conexión a mi base de datos con mysql

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar, se lo agradecería, también he revisado que los datos de usuario y contraseña sean correctos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Si, estoy generando una kb nueva con Genexus 18 con Generador Java, Tomcat y MySQL, he descargado el conector JDBC  y se encuentra declarado en el classpath que menciona la documentación de Genexus, al intentar crear una Datastore a Mysql con mi base de datos, aparece que Java no encuentra un Driver JDBC, he colocado también el conector JDBC en el directorio raíz de mi kb y en la instalación de Genexus para que lo identifique pero no logro realizar una conexión a mi base de datos
